# Clone a logstash event N number of times with the value from the message itself

Tags: logstash, logstash-filter

How can I clone a event "N" number of times, where the value of N comes from the event itself.

For eg. Input event is like this :

```
"Event1 [Host] Machine A (4 licenses)"
"Event2 [Host] Machine A (2 licenses)"
"Event3 [Host] Machine A (3 licenses)"
```

I want an output that would give me a total of 9 events after cloning

```
"Event1 [Host] Machine A"
"Event1 [Host] Machine A"
"Event1 [Host] Machine A"
"Event1 [Host] Machine A"

"Event2 [Host] Machine A"
"Event2 [Host] Machine A"

"Event3 [Host] Machine A"
"Event3 [Host] Machine A"
"Event3 [Host] Machine A"
```

Here's what I've tried :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/code/file.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}


filter {

   if [message] =~ /licenses/ {  
    grok {        
            match => [ "msg", "%{GREEDYDATA:junk} \(%{NUMBER:number} licenses\)"]
    }   

  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I have the value to loop in "number" variable, but how do I clone that "number of times"

Answer (score 0):

Logstash doesn't have a looping construct, so it feels like a good time to drop into ruby.

To clone the event in ruby, check out the code that the [clone filter](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-clone/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/clone.rb) uses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it for anyone curious about this :

```
        grok {        
            match => [ "msg", "%{GREEDYDATA:junk} \(%{DATA:number} licenses\)"]
        }   
        ruby {
            code => '
                totallicenses = event.get("number")
                totallicenses.to_i.times { |i|
                    newevent = event.to_hash
                    generated = LogStash::Event.new(newevent)
                    new_event_block.call(generated)
                }
                event.cancel
                '
        }
```

The last `event.cancel` is to cancel the current event, and duplicate that event N number of times. Otherwise, you can reduce the count to N-1 in the loop itself.